# Centos openssl vulnerability high OpenSSL Running Version Prior to 1.0.1t

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, openssl

I have run a security check and it came back with 6 high vulnerabilities.

```
OpenSSL Running Version Prior to 1.0.1t
OpenSSL Running Version Prior to 1.0.1t
OpenSSL Running Version Prior to 1.0.1o
OpenSSL Running Version Prior to 1.0.1o
OpenSSL Running Version Prior to 1.0.1s (DROWN)
OpenSSL Running Version Prior to 1.0.1s (DROWN)
```

I am here as a last result (i have googled) so many conflicting articles on updating i was really hoping the cmd.

```
yum update openssl
```

Would solve my issue but no help i get.

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                         | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest                                      | 2.3 kB     00:00     
1521 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No packages marked for update
```

I have seen a few articles about building from src and then articles saying you should definitively not do this what is right I really want to make sure my server is secure.

My openssl version is: OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015

I am running centos on AWS ec2 any idea how to update? this does not help https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/openssl/

Please help.

Comment: If you are worried.  I would manually build OpenSSL from source then replace the existing binary.  You don't mention what version of CentOS.

Comment: [How to upgrade OpenSSL in CentOS 6.5 / Linux / Unix from source?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952287/how-to-upgrade-openssl-in-centos-6-5-linux-unix-from-source)

Comment: If you can't do that, you should conact RedHat, and inform them they should update their copy of the OpenSSL repostitory.  Please have questions migrated, instead of [Cross-posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373435/centos-openssl-vulnerability-high-openssl-running-version-prior-to-1-0-1t) across multiple sites, in the future.